# Sending malicious email as a test

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, mailscanner

I have set up a working SMTP relay together with MailScanner.
This SMTP relay is not — and will not be — able to relay email from *the outside*, only local email.

Is it possible to send a *malicious* email with the terminal? I have googled around but could not find anything that could answer my question.
For example, I want to use:

```
echo "{malicious-string}" | mail name@email.com
```

What could the `"{malicious-string}"` be?

Comment: just send the eicar test virus

Comment: There is also the GTUBE (Generic Test for Unsolicited Bulk Email) to test your spam filters: https://spamassassin.apache.org/gtube/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the EICAR test virus.  http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html

```
echo 'X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*' | mail
```

Edit: Be sure to read Michael Hampton's as well!

Comment: Ineed this worked, but I discovered that my Palo Alto firewall did take care of it instead of mailscanner. Seems like mailscanner did not catch it.

Thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: It might have detected it, if it had actually been in a file attachment. e.g. `echo -n 'X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*' > ducklin.html`

Comment: @MichaelHampton My firewall did catch it also. So I had to psychically bypass the fw

Answer (score 30):

To be sure, you should use the EICAR test virus, and *attach* it to the email, rather than simply putting it in the body.

```
echo -n 'X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*' > ducklin.docx
echo "Here is 10 million dollars" | mailx -a ducklin.docx user@example.com
```